# .Net solution trying to build using Inedo BuildMaster

Tags: .net, frameworks, buildmaster

When i try to execute my workfolw in BuildMaster, it's throwing me the following errors. It seems like there is a PFX certificate issue. When i run the same solution in Visual Studio, It's working fine without any issues. It is an existing application, built with PFX Certificate and password protected.

Can you please help me out in fixing that.

> ERROR:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5):
>   error MSB3326: Cannot import the following key file: . The key file
>   may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the
>   certificate again or import the certificate manually into the current
>   user's personal certificate store.ERROR:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5):
>   error MSB3321: Importing key file "ppmillinous.pfx" was canceled.
>   INFO: Done building project "wa5invqz.tmp_proj" -- FAILED. INFO: Done
>   building project "POWERPitch.csproj" -- FAILED. INFO: Done building
>   project "POWERPitch.sln" -- FAILED.ERROR: Build failed (msbuild
>   returned 1).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest doing the following:

1) Create a pfx file that is password protected

2) Either import the password protected cert again or import the password protected cert to the current user's personal certificate store.

Note that if the pfx file you're using is already password protected, you can skip the first step.

Comment: I have tried that way.. But still i am getting the same error.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest updating your question with (A) Actual detail about what you're trying to do and (B) Actual detail about what you've done.

Comment: A. I am trying to build the code using BuildMaster. First i brought the source code to BuildMaster and then build the code in BuildMaster. When i build it's throwing me the above error. "The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or import the certificate manually into the current user's personal certificate store.". I tried installing that certificate in Build code folder in BuildMaster also but it is still throwing the same error

Comment: 1) Update your question with information, not just a comment that will be lost or not seen by anyone else. 2) Of course you're trying to build something with buildmaster. It's in the name. What's your workflow step? What's the specific step trying to do? Why does it need a certificate? How did you get the certificate? Does the certificate have a password? How did you verify this? (This is not an exclusive list of questions- these are the fundamentals that you need to answer and understand yourself before you can expect any random person to be able to help you.)