# Importing Key file issue while building using BuildMaster

Tags: c#, msbuild, workflow, pfx, buildmaster

When i try to Build my code in BuildMaster, i am getting the following error.

ERROR: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5): error MSB3326: Cannot import the following key file: . The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or import the certificate manually into the current user's personal certificate store.ERROR: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5): error MSB3321: Importing key file "ppmillinous.pfx" was canceled. INFO: Done building project "iok50yfy.tmp_proj" -- FAILED. INFO: Done building project "POWERPitch.csproj" -- FAILED. INFO: Done building project "POWERPitch.sln" -- FAILED.ERROR: Build failed (msbuild returned 1).

Is there anything which i need to set in MSBuild properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BuildMaster .Net Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592119/buildmaster-net-framework)

Comment: I tried with that link but could not fix my issue. Can you please help me out in fixing this issue.

Comment: Try some of these suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815366